# Return value of db.insert in sqflite?

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter, sqflite

Insert function on database in sqflite returns id of row inserted. But I want to know what it returns if an error occurs after getting an error during insertion.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used sqflite package which is used by flutter to work with sqlite3. When we insert a row in table using insert method, it returns row id if successfully inserted or an error if there was some problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Check now again if it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

It should throw an error and then you can let it return whatever you want.